# Can we declare a variable in tcl which behave kind of like instance variable in Java i.e. once declared can be accessed anywhere within a class?

Tags: tcl

I have tried this:

```
global svcCallWithOneChar ""

if {[catch {set "svcCallWithOneChar = [mimic.list :prefix \"l\"]"} errmsg]} {
   puts $errmsg
} else {
    puts "###### Svc Call With prefix set to Single Char \n $svcCallWithOneChar  \n ##################"
}
```

but it produces this error

> can't read "svcCallWithOneChar =

The reason is: It goes to else condition and then can't access the result stored in svcCallWithOneChar.

Comment: Your question is not necessarily related to its title when looking at the snippet. As Peter kindly elaborates, there are many more syntactic issues before any OO would come into play. Besides, example, question statement and title should be consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing object-oriented programming in Tcl, there are several options. In TclOO, you define an instance variable like this:

```
oo::class create Foo {
    variable thevariable
    ...
}
```

The variable `thevariable` is now accessible in all methods in all instances of the `Foo` class.

As for your example code, I can't really figure out what you are trying to do. A couple of notes, though:

The arguments to the `global` command are variable names to be linked between the global scope and the current scope. Your invocation, if it is inside a procedure, creates two local variables: `svcCallWithOneChar` and "" (yes, that is a legal variable name).

The invocation `set "svcCallWithOneChar = [mimic.list :prefix \"l\"]"` is not an assignment. It's the single-argument form of `set`, so it tries to access the value of a variable named `svcCallWithOneChar = foo` (if `foo` is the return value of the `mimic.list :prefix \"l\"` invocation). If the latter invocation results in the empty string, the variable name becomes `svcCallWithOneChar =`, which is exactly what your error message says.

Also, even though `mimic.list :prefix \"l\"` is invoked within a double-quoted string, the text within brackets is not part of the string (the result of the invocation is embedded verbatim in the string, though). So escaping the double quotes in the second argument to `mimic.list` means that the command gets the argument `"l"`, not `l`.